# Function works fine with chrome but not in IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I have a problem running js script in firefox and IE but it works fine on Chrome.
And i have not foud any satisfactory answer so far.
I have to build a form to order meals , and i must be able to add supplements .
The user must click here:

```
<a href="#"  class="ajoutPlat"><img src="images/plusdetour.png" width="25" height="25" alt="plusdetour"/>
```

and i should add to my html a dropdown list cloned from a hidden div.

**HTML**

```
<table border="0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Supplements disponibles</th>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>________________</th>

    </tr>
</thead>

<tr>
    <td><p>Plat supplementaire</p></td>
    <td><a href="#"  class="ajoutPlat"><img src="images/plusdetour.png" width="25" height="25" alt="plusdetour"/></a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><p>Garniture supplementaire</p></td>
    <td><a href="#" class="ajoutGarniture"><img src="images/plusdetour.png" width="25" height="25" alt="plusdetour"/></a>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><p>Pain Supplemaentaire</p></td>
    <td><a href="#" class="ajoutPain"><img src="images/plusdetour.png" width="25" height="25" alt="plusdetour"/></a>
    </td>
</tr
<tr>
    <td><p>Potage</p></td>
    <td><a href="#" class="ajoutPotage"><img src="images/plusdetour.png" width="25" height="25" alt="plusdetour"/></a>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php
foreach ($elementsSupplements as $element) {

    echo '<tr>'
    . '<td>'
    . '<p>' . $element . '</p>'
    . '</td>'
    . '<td>'
    . '<a href="#" class="ajout' . $element . '"><img src="images/plusdetour.png" width="25" height="25" alt="plusdetour"/></a>'
    . '</td>'
    ;
}
?>

</table>
<br/>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
var z = 0;
var y = 0;
var x = 0;
var w = 0;
var lim1 = "Le nombre de plats , garnitures ou potages supplementaires est limité a 1";
var lim10 = "Le supplément selectionné ne sera pas rajouté , vous avez atteint la limite fixée a 10";
var choix = "Le potage n'est pas disponible si vous avez pris un plat et/ou une garniture supplémentaire";

$(".ajoutPlat").live('click', function() {
    if (z < 10 && x < 1 && w < 1) {
        plat = $('.plat:first').clone();
        $("<tr><td><p>+1 Plat</p></td><td id='addplat" + z + "'></td></tr></br>").appendTo("#supplements");
        plat.appendTo("#addplat" + z);
        z++;
        x++;
    } else {
        if (z > 10) {
            alert(lim10);
        } else if (x > 0) {
            alert(lim1);
        }
    }

});
$(".ajoutPotage").live('click', function() {
    if (z < 10) {
        if (w < 1) {
            if (x === 0 && y === 0) {
                plat = $('.potage:first').clone();
                $("<tr><td><p>+1 Potage</p></td><td id='addPotage" + z + "'></td></tr></br>").appendTo("#supplements");
                plat.appendTo("#addPotage" + z);
                z++;
                w++;
            } else {
                alert(choix);
            }
        } else {
            alert(lim1);
        }
    } else {
        alert(lim10);
    }

});

$(".ajoutGarniture").live('click', function() {
    if (z < 10 && y < 1 && w < 1) {
        garniture = $('.garniture:first').clone();
        $("<tr><td><p>+1 Garniture</p></td><td id='addGarniture" + z + "'></td></tr></br>").appendTo("#supplements");
        garniture.appendTo("#addGarniture" + z);
        z++;
        y++;
    } else {
        if (z > 10) {
            alert(lim10);
        } else if (y > 0) {
            alert(lim1);
        }
    }

});

$(".ajoutJournal-Eure-Info").live('click', function() {
    if (z < 10)
    {
        jei = $('.Journal-Eure-Info:first').clone();
        $("<tr><td><p>+1 Journal</p></td><td id='addJournal-Eure-Info" + z + "' class='cellCentre'></td></tr></br>").appendTo("#supplements");
        jei.appendTo("#addJournal-Eure-Info" + z);
        z++;
    }
    else
    {
        alert(lim10);
    }
});

$(".ajoutJournal-La-dépêche").live('click', function() {
    if (z < 10)
    {
        jld = $('.Journal-La-dépêche:first').clone();
        $("<tr><td><p>+1 Journal</p></td><td id='addJournal-La-dépêche" + z + "' class='cellCentre'></td></tr></br>").appendTo("#supplements");
        jld.appendTo("#addJournal-La-dépêche" + z);
        z++;
    }
    else
    {
        alert(lim10);
    }
});

$(".ajoutPanier-de-fruits").live('click', function() {
    if (z < 10)
    {
        pdf = $('.Panier-de-fruits:first').clone();
        $("<tr><td><p>+1 Panier</p></td><td id='addPanier-de-fruits" + z + "' class='cellCentre'></td></tr></br>").appendTo("#supplements");
        pdf.appendTo("#addPanier-de-fruits" + z);
        z++;
    }
    else
    {
        alert(lim10);
    }
});
$(".ajoutCroissant").live('click', function() {
    if (z < 10)
    {
        crs = $('.Croissant:first').clone();
        $("<tr><td><p>+1 Croissant</p></td><td id='addCroissant" + z + "' class='cellCentre'></td></tr></br>").appendTo("#supplements");
        crs.appendTo("#addCroissant" + z);
        z++;
    }
    else
    {
        alert(lim10);
    }
});


$(".ajoutPain-au-Chocolat").live('click', function() {
    if (z < 10)
    {
        pac = $('.Pain-au-Chocolat:first').clone();
        $("<tr><td><p>+1 Pain choco</p></td><td id='addPain-au-Chocolat" + z + "' class='cellCentre'></td></tr></br>").appendTo("#supplements");
        pac.appendTo("#addPain-au-Chocolat" + z);
        z++;
    }
    else
    {
        alert(lim10);
    }
});

$(".ajoutPain").live('click', function() {
    if (z < 10)
    {
        pan = $('.pain:first').clone();
        $("<tr><td><p>+1 Pain</p></td><td id='addPain" + z + "'></td></tr></br>").appendTo("#supplements");
        pan.appendTo("#addPain" + z);
        z++;
    }
    else
    {
        alert(lim10);
    }
});
});
```

It worked fine so far.And i'd like to know why it works no more.

---

**Solution**

Turns out the problem was $.browser in my jQuery, to solve the problem , i used

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.0.0.js"></script>
```

Now everything works fine with FF IE chrome and Safari.
The problem was found using Firebug , FF plugin.

Comment: TIP: What version of jQuery are you using? `.live()` has been deprecated on v1.7.

Comment: replace live() with on(), it is deprecated in 1.7version

Comment: Picking just part of your code: `pan.appendTo("#addPain" + z);` This won't work, because the element with id _addPain + z_ it's being dynamically created just before.

Comment: Also, it may be just a typo, but you have an unclosed _tr_ tag there. `</tr <tr>`.

Comment: @MelanciaUK +1 for asking what version he's using and not just telling him to change his code to something that may well be totally wrong!

Comment: well i'm new at web programming an i had no idea it .live was deprecated

Comment: jQuery 1.4.4. what about `code`pan.appendTo("#addPain" + z); `code` ?

Comment: I'm glad you sorted it out! Unfortunately I had two straight days of madness at work, so I wasn't able to check your fiddle. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks anyway, research and resolve problems is part of the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**: don't use `live`. Use delegation. Jquery deprecated the .live() method back in version 1.7 (which is like 4 years old, now). Event bubbling, in turn, is the natural way to deal with asynchronously created nodes.

```
$(function() {
var z = 0;
var y = 0;
var x = 0;
var w = 0;
var lim1 = "Le nombre de plats , garnitures ou potages supplementaires est limité a 1";
var lim10 = "Le supplément selectionné ne sera pas rajouté , vous avez atteint la limite fixée a 10";
var choix = "Le potage n'est pas disponible si vous avez pris un plat et/ou une garniture supplémentaire";

$(document).on('click',".ajoutPlat", function() {
    ...
});

$(document).on('click', ".ajoutPotage", function() {
    ...
});

$(document).on('click', ".ajoutGarniture", function() {
    ...
});

$(document).on('click', ".ajoutJournal-Eure-Info", function() {
    ...
});

$(document).on('click',".ajoutJournal-La-dépêche", function() {
    ...
});

$(document).on('click',".ajoutPanier-de-fruits", function() {
    ...
});

$(document).on('click', ".ajoutCroissant", function() {
   ...
});


$(document).on('click',".ajoutPain-au-Chocolat", function() {
    ...
});

$(document).on('click',".ajoutPain", function() {
    ...
});
```

**Second**: pay attention not to try appending to objects that doesn't exist yet. For example

```
plat = $('.plat:first').clone();
$("<tr><td><p>+1 Plat</p></td><td id='addplat" + z + "'></td></tr></br>").appendTo("#supplements");
plat.appendTo("#addplat" + z);
```

Might or might not work, depending on the browser and the position of the stars. The correct way would be

```
var plat = $('.plat:first').clone();
var newtr= $('<tr></tr>');
var addplat=$('<td id="addplat' + z + '"></td>');
plat.appendTo(addplat);
newtr.append('<td><p>+1 Plat</p></td>');
newtr.append(addplat);
newtr.appendTo("#supplements");
```

See, you don't need to make jQuery go search the DOM for `"#addplat" + z` (which might not be in the DOM by then), because **you already know** which node is your `addplat` object, even before adding it to the DOM.

**Third** I'm not sure about special characters in IDs. They should work, but I'd rather keep everything in ascii characters. For example, use class `ajoutJournal-La-depeche` instead of `ajoutJournal-La-dépêche`. Just to be on the safe side.

Comment: Good answer, but don't forget to mention why are you suggesting `.on()` instead of `.live()`. We both know, but it's good to keep as part of the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, i'll put that on trial, if it works , you saved my day

Comment: In that case... we're screwed :(

Comment: I've replaced as suggested .live by .on and it's not working.The new way to append my element though was a succes , even if my problem remains unsolved.Thank you anyway

Comment: Is jQuery 1.4.4 so bad ?maybe i can change my version?

Comment: It's too old. jQuery 1.4.4 dates from year 2008. Google chrome didn't exist back then. jQuery serves the purpose of simplifying DOM manipulation through abstraction, and browser interoperability through the facade pattern. Don't expect interoperability for current browsers with an outdated lib.

Comment: Thank you , i'l change my jQ; version and i tell you the result

Comment: @amenadiel About jQuery 1.4.4 with chrome, the problem is it actually work with chrome a that version.I updated to 2.1.1 and now it works with .on but still not with IE and FF.

Comment: Yes, I know. But browser interoperability is a general purpose, I wasn't addressing this particular issue.

Comment: What if you try to make it work in jsfiddle? that way we can all make some trial and error experiments.

Comment: well i don't know jsfiddle, i'll check

Comment: in js fiddle you can paste your HTML and js to share, so if you leave a jsfiddle link in here we can try to solve your code, even if it's just a mockup of the actual page